# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react components and props. Here's exception below.
What I'm doing wrong?

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a
>   function, not undefined

```
class Component extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('reactContainer')
)
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/armwr/pen/OWqajw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

```
class Component extends React.component {
```

you used small `c` in `React.component` instead of that use `C`:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
```

Check the working code:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('reactContainer')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='reactContainer'></div>
```